# how to hide password while typing in console in java

Tags: java, console, passwords, masking

I am developing a online order management system in java connecting MySql to run in console where I need to login using userid and password. so, here I need to mask the password while typing in console. can anyone pls, help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

The class [Console](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Console.html) has a method `readPassword()` that might be helpful in your case.

Answer (score 0):

`char[] password = System.console().readPassword("password:");`

notice: you can't run this code in IDE, you have to execute on terminal.